# CSV Conversion Program not doing what the methods are built to do

Tags: c#, csv

I have built a CSV Conversion program and one of my methods is `BuildRecordAndWriteOutput()` and I have built it to output the new items stored in the outputBuffers but to also SKIP the commas that are in some of the fields. This method works perfectly fine in some of my other programs but with this program it is splitting at the commas in the fields when it should not be.

An example is a name field may have `Company Name, Example` and that will be in column A but when I reprint it out in the output file it will be `Company Name` `Example` and they will be shift over 1 column instead of being in 1 field as one.

My confusion is that , though my code may not be the most elegant or the best approach, I must be missing something in how I am calling my methods or variables.

I have been scanning and comparing the code to the other programs where the method works perfect and no luck! Can anyone see what I can not in this?

My Source Code

---

```
class Program
{
    // File object variables
    static TextFieldParser input = new TextFieldParser("PPVendingPricing.csv");
    static StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("convertedInventoryItemListTacMed.csv");

    // Input and output buffer variables
    static string[] inputBuffer;
    static string[] outputBuffer = new string[40];


    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures();

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        input.Close();
        output.Close();
        Console.Read();
    }

     /*
     * This method reads the input file and fill data structures
     * that are used to organize the data before moving selected
     * fields to the output buffer.
     */ 
    public static void ReadInputAndBuildDataStructures()
    {
        input.SetDelimiters(",");

        input.ReadFields(); // Skip the header record.

        while (!input.EndOfData)
        {
            inputBuffer = input.ReadFields(); // Read a CSV record in to the inputBuffer. 
            {
                SetOutputBufferDefaultValues(); // Put default values in the output buffer
                MapInputFieldsToOutputFields(); // Move fields from the input buffer to the output buffer.
                BuildRecordAndWriteOutput(); // Build record from output buffer and write it.
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * This method loads default values into the output
    * buffer (string array). Some of these values will be 
    * replaced before the output buffer is written to the file.
    */
    public static void SetOutputBufferDefaultValues()
    {
        // Initialize all fields to empty.
        for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            outputBuffer[i] = "";
        }

        // Update selected fields with default values.
        outputBuffer[7] = "Inc";
        outputBuffer[10] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[11] = "FIFO";
        outputBuffer[15] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[17] = "Main";
        outputBuffer[19] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[21] = "Inc";
        outputBuffer[25] = "Main";
        outputBuffer[28] = "Periods of Supply";
        outputBuffer[32] = "1";
        outputBuffer[35] = "By Overall Item Qty";
        outputBuffer[36] = "TRUE";
        outputBuffer[37] = "TRUE";
    }

    /*
    * This method maps selected values from the input buffer
    * to the appropriate position in the output buffer.
    */
    public static void MapInputFieldsToOutputFields()
    {
        outputBuffer[0] = inputBuffer[26];
        outputBuffer[1] = inputBuffer[38];
        outputBuffer[2] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[3] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[4] = inputBuffer[40];
        outputBuffer[5] = inputBuffer[3];
        outputBuffer[6] = inputBuffer[27];
        outputBuffer[12] = inputBuffer[13];
        outputBuffer[13] = inputBuffer[39];
        outputBuffer[14] = inputBuffer[38] + " " +inputBuffer[40];
        //skipping outputBuffer[16] position 17 on spreadsheet
        outputBuffer[20] = inputBuffer[36];
        outputBuffer[22] = inputBuffer[37];
        outputBuffer[23] = inputBuffer[39];
        outputBuffer[24] = inputBuffer[40];
        outputBuffer[29] = inputBuffer[27];
        outputBuffer[33] = inputBuffer[18];
        outputBuffer[34] = inputBuffer[19];
        outputBuffer[38] = inputBuffer[39];
    }

    /*
     * This method uses the fields (array elements) in the output
     * buffer to assemble a CSV record (string variable). The
     * CSV record is then written to the output file.
     */
    public static void BuildRecordAndWriteOutput()
    {
        string record = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            if (outputBuffer[i].Contains(","))
            {
                string x = "\"" + outputBuffer[i] + "\"";
                record += x;
            }
            else
            {
                record += outputBuffer[i];
            }
            if (i < outputBuffer.Length - 1)
            {
                record += ",";
            }
        }

        output.WriteLine(record);
    }
}
```

---

Here is a picture of broken output CSV file

[image]

As you can see, the top row is perfect but the bottom row is shifted because it split on the comma that was `"TAPE CLOTH 1 - ADHESIVE BANDAGE ROLL, 2.50cm X 5m"` and since  it had a comma when it was read in it split at it on the output BUT my method should be taking care of this.

Why is my method not working? Am I calling it wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing to set the [HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx) property. `input.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true` should solve your problem.

> If a field is enclosed in quotation marks, for example, abc,
>   "field2a,field2b", field3 and this property is True, then all text
>   enclosed in quotation marks will be returned as is; this example would
>   return abc|field2a,field2b|field3. Setting this property to False
>   would make this example return abc|"field2a|field2b"|field3.

Comment: I wonder why it worked on my other programs then? Any idea why? And thank you for helping I will test your answer :)

Comment: Also, should that line of code be placed in my method or my static variables above?

Comment: You should put it before the call to `ReadFields`. For uniformity I'd put it together with `input.SetDelimiters(",")`

Comment: I placed the line above my `input.SetDelimiters(",");` and it did not seem to work. I am sure i am doing it wrong.